# Why does my code return incorrect values for my weighted average calculations?

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first question on StackOverflow, so bear with me if I get some of the procedure/posting standards incorrect.

My goal is to assign each student in the dataset a weighted average based on their test and quiz scores. Tests constitute 90% of this weighted average, and quizzes make up the remaining 10%. There is an additional caveat that if a test score is below 60, this score receives an additional 5 points (without changing the original test score). This entire process is to be done using a VBA programmed macro.

The problem I am having is that the calculated averages are wrong. (see picture, some scores are over 100 which should not be possible) I have tried to isolate the error by looking at the individual test and quiz averages, and so far I believe the error lies in the calculation of the test average but I'm not quite sure what exactly the problem is. Even when I remove the if statement that accounts for the "curve" I still end up with scores over 100. This makes me think there is an issue with the way I am calculating the averages. I have provided the code for my macro below. If there are any other problems with how I wrote this macro, please let me know I am still new to VBA.

```
Sub SetTwo()
Dim gradeAvg As Integer
Dim testAvg As Double
Dim quizAvg As Double
For i = 2 To 104
    gradeAvg = 0
    testAvg = 0
    quizAvg = 0
    For j = 6 To 13
        If j <= 8 Then
            If Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, j) < 60 Then
            testAvg = testAvg + Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, j) + 5
            Else
            testAvg = testAvg + Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Else
        quizAvg = quizAvg + Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
    testAvg = (testAvg / 300) * 90
    quizAvg = (quizAvg / 100) * 10
    gradeAvg = testAvg + quizAvg
    Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, 13) = gradeAvg
Next i
End Sub
```

[Here is a sample of the dataset, with the averages calculated incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjYJr.png)

Comment: Should j go up to 12 rather than 13 in the For loop?

Comment: You are correct, it should be 12, not 13. I made the mistake of believing that everything online is true. I was told for loops in VBA end after the counter hits the specified value, not that it would continue to loop that final time. This ended up skewing my results since the calculated average was included in my quizAverage variable.

Comment: You don't need vba for this at all, unless you are just trying to do some VBA for fun.  A simple formula can calculate these.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tad bit embarassing. After playing around with the code a little more, I found my issue. It seems the bound for my inner for loops was wrong. I included the cell that contains the "average" value which ended up distorting my calculations and resulted in my calculated values going over 100.

For those interested, I have included the code for the correct macro below:

```
Sub SetTwo()
Dim gradeAvg As Integer
Dim testAvg As Double
Dim quizAvg As Double
For i = 2 To 104
    gradeAvg = 0
    testAvg = 0
    quizAvg = 0
    For j = 6 To 12
        If j < 9 Then
            If Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, j) < 60 Then
            testAvg = testAvg + Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, j) + 5
            Else
            testAvg = testAvg + Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, j)
            End If
        Else
        quizAvg = quizAvg + Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
    testAvg = (testAvg / 300) * 90
    quizAvg = (quizAvg / 100) * 10
    gradeAvg = testAvg + quizAvg
    Worksheets("Set2").Cells(i, 13) = gradeAvg
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

the following sentence has 1 extra, it calculates including the "Average" cell

```
For j = 6 To 13
```

Should be j = 6 To 12

Hope it helps ! I did simulations and went good.

Comment: Yup, I ended up finding out this was the problem maybe 10 minutes after posting my question. I can't say I'm not a tad bit embarrassed that it ended up being such a simple mistake, I really thought I had some complex issue on my hands.